# How to apply slideUp & slideDown functions to one div at a time?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, jsfiddle

Everything is in the title:

```
var extended = 0;

$('.info_btn_m').off('click');
$('.info_btn_m').on('click', function() {
    if(extended == 0) {
        $('.detail_m').slideDown();
        extended = 1;
    } else {
        $('.detail_m').slideUp();
        extended = 0;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r54vdkv1/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)**

```
$('.info_btn_m').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest("div").next('.detail_m').slideToggle();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r54vdkv1/2/)**

Comment: To two divs keeps sliding at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

With your particular HTML structure you can use a combination of [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.detail_m')
```

eg. fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1k87v909/

Comment: @Zac Note that you should also use `slideToggle` as Bala's answer suggests, otherwise you need a separate `extended` var for each sliding `div`